# Right align memoir chapter style + appendix problem

Tags: memoir, chapters

Merry christmas to everyone.
I'm trying to make a LyX template since I have to write three reports over the next 12 months. 
I'm using memoir and chapterstyle demo2. How can I

1) Right align the chapter number (the name is already right aligned) and

2) Change it from e.g. "one" to "Chapter 1"?

3) Can I do the same thing on my appendix? I.e., make right align and make it start with "Appendix A" instead of "A"? [image]

This is my preamble so far:

```
\chapterstyle{demo2}
\makepagestyle{mystyle}
\makeheadrule {mystyle}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness} 
\makeevenhead{mystyle}{\small\leftmark}{}{}
\makeoddhead{mystyle}{\small\rightmark}{}{}
\makeevenfoot{mystyle}{}{\thepage }{} 
\makeoddfoot{mystyle}{}{\thepage}{}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a variant of the `demo2` chapter style:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeatletter
\makechapterstyle{demo2var}{%
  \chapterstyle{default}
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\sffamily}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\chaptitlefont}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{\raggedleft}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont
     \ifanappendix Appendix \else Chapter \fi\thechapter}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
    \hrule\vskip\onelineskip \raggedleft \chaptitlefont ##1}
  \renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{%
    \vskip\onelineskip \hrule\vskip \afterchapskip}
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{3\baselineskip}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternonum}{%
    \vphantom{\chapnumfont One}
    \afterchapternum%
    \vskip\topskip}
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{2\onelineskip}}
\makeatother

\chapterstyle{demo2var}

%% add here the changes for headers and footers

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Fundamentals}

\appendix

\chapter{Minor points}

\end{document}
```

[image: Chapter]

[image: Appendix]

Comment: @Lars_CPH It just took a minute: find the definition of the `demo2` chapter style, and figure out what changes had to be made. Not easy for a beginner, but if you're interested, you can spot the differences by looking at the code in `memoir.cls` (lines 3247–3262). Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: I am interested (I do some other coding, but in this community, Im new and unskilled/useless) - where/how do I find the memoir.cls?

Comment: @Lars_CPH It depends on what TeX distribution and OS you are using. On Unix, the command line `less $(kpsewhich memoir.cls)` will do.

Comment: Okay. I'll take a look at it after christmas :). Thanks again.